# fastest way to remove string quotes encapsulating a dictionary type in pandas

Tags: pandas, string, dictionary, export-to-csv, python-re

I have some `pd.DataFrame`; elements of which were orginally of type `dict`. However, I wrote the `pd.DataFrame` to type `csv`. The problem i encounter now is on reading the file back to `pd.DataFrame` the dictionaries are read by default as type `string`. So for example this is the output, I get on reading the `csv` file.

```
df.iloc[0,0]
"{'maxAge': 1, 'priceHint': {'raw': 2, 'fmt': '2', 'longFmt': '2'}}"
```

my desired output is to remove the string quotes `""` encapsulating the dictionary, so it should be like

desired output

```
df.iloc[0,0]
{'maxAge': 1, 'priceHint': {'raw': 2, 'fmt': '2', 'longFmt': '2'}}
```

my `pd.DataFrame` is rather large (>30,000 elements). What is the fastest way to achive this? most likely without running any loops. I would guess, some combination of options at the `pd.read_csv` level could do the trick but i haven't been able to figure it how.

Edit 1.0

here is a `pd.DataFrame` to allow replication of the input

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col_a':["{'maxAge': 1, 'priceHint': {'raw': 2, 'fmt': '2', 'longFmt': '2'}}",\
                   "{'maxAge': 2, 'priceHint': {'raw': 3, 'fmt': '3', 'longFmt': '3'}}",\
                  "{'maxAge': 2, 'priceHint': {'raw': 3, 'fmt': '3', 'longFmt': '3'}}",\
                  "{'maxAge': 1, 'priceHint': {'raw': 2, 'fmt': '2', 'longFmt': '2'}}"]})
```

Comment: `eval`, but you probably still need a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Since the dictionaries are the string representation of a dictionary, you'll need to use an `eval` method to actually make it behave like a dictionary again (simply attempting to remove the quotes won't do anything). The simplest way to do this will be with `ast.literal_eval` which is a safer alternative to directly calling python's `eval` method.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col_a':["{'maxAge': 1, 'priceHint': {'raw': 2, 'fmt': '2', 'longFmt': '2'}}",\
                   "{'maxAge': 2, 'priceHint': {'raw': 3, 'fmt': '3', 'longFmt': '3'}}",\
                  "{'maxAge': 2, 'priceHint': {'raw': 3, 'fmt': '3', 'longFmt': '3'}}",\
                  "{'maxAge': 1, 'priceHint': {'raw': 2, 'fmt': '2', 'longFmt': '2'}}"]})

df.iloc[0, 0] # Each element of this Series is a string
# "{'maxAge': 1, 'priceHint': {'raw': 2, 'fmt': '2', 'longFmt': '2'}}"
```

Using `ast.literal_eval` with Series.apply

```
import ast

df["col_a"] = df["col_a"].apply(ast.literal_eval)

df.iloc[0, 0] # Each element of this Series is a dictionary
# {'maxAge': 1, 'priceHint': {'raw': 2, 'fmt': '2', 'longFmt': '2'}}
```

Alternatively, since you're reading this in from a csv, you can apply ast.literal_eval while you read in the data via `pd.read_csv`:

```
df = pd.read_csv("path/to/file.csv", converters={"col_a": ast.literal_eval})
```

This shouldn't improve performance, but can simplify your code a little bit.